# Fade in Datatable on Click of Button Filter

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datatable

I'm using jQuery to filter a DataTable with buttons. I'd like it so that when I click the buttons, the table fades in everytime. I've tried a few options but none seem to react to the click.

Could anybody help me out? If you're wondering about the odd table structure, this is simply done like this for aesthetic appeal for the final product. We are ultimately filtering on columnDef[2], despite it being hidden.

It currently uses .draw() to do this.

**HTML**

```
 <body>
    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons" role="group" aria-label="Basic radio toggle button group">
        <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio1" autocomplete="off" checked>
        <label class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm" id="selectOption1" for="btnradio1">Option1 andOption2</label>

        <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio2" autocomplete="off">
        <label class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm" id="selectOption2" for="btnradio2">Option2</label>
    </div>
    <br>
    <hr>
    </div>

    <div class="main">
        <table class="table mydatatable" id="mydatatable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th> </th>
                    <th> </th>
                    <th> </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="myTable">
                <tr>
                    <td><br><br>
                        <span style='font-size:36px;color:#4da4d0'><i class="fa-solid fa-book"></i></span>
                    </td></a>
                    <td>
                        <span class="tableTitle"><br><a href="https://www.google.com" target='_blank'>
                                Name</a><br></span>
                        <span class="tableNewbie"><span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Option1&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <span class="tableDate"><span><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="far fa-calendar"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                11 October 2022</span></span>
                    </td>
                    <td>Option1</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td><br><br>
                        <span style='font-size:36px;color:#4da4d0'><i class="fa-solid fa-book"></i></span>
                    </td></a>
                    <td>
                        <span class="tableTitle"><br><a href="https://www.google.com" target='_blank'>
                                Name</a><br></span>
                        <span class="tableNewbie"><span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Option2&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <span class="tableDate"><span><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="far fa-calendar"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                13 October 2022</span></span>
                    </td>
                    <td>Option2</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td><br><br>
                        <span style='font-size:36px;color:#4da4d0'><i class="fa-solid fa-book"></i></span>
                    </td></a>
                    <td>
                        <span class="tableTitle"><br><a href="https://www.google.com" target='_blank'>
                                Name</a><br></span>
                        <span class="tableNewbie"><span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Option2&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <span class="tableDate"><span><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="far fa-calendar"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                18 October 2022</span></span>
                    </td>
                    <td>Option2</td>
                </tr>
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script>
                    // Pull in the Data Tables via jQuery
                    $(document).ready(function () {
                        var oTable = $('.mydatatable').DataTable({
                            "pageLength": 50,
                            "search": { regex: true },
                            "dom": "<<t>>",
                            // We need those columns to be searchable, but not visible
                            "columnDefs": [{
                                targets: [2],
                                visible: false,
                                searchable: true,
                            },
                            {
                                targets: 0,
                                width: "6%",
                            }
                            ]
                        });

                        // Option Selector
                        $("#selectOption1").on('click', function () {
                            oTable.columns(2).search('Option1|Option2', true, false).draw();
                        });
                        $("#selectOption2").on('click', function () {
                            oTable.columns(2).search('Option2', true, false).draw();
                        });
                    })
                </script>
```

**Load for the example:**

```
<!-- Jquery -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Datatables -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<!-- Icons -->
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/f3135b3376.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: I may have misunderstood the question (in which case, my apologies) - but how can you fade in something which is already fully visible? And doesn't there also need to be something which "fades out" or otherwise hides the table in response to a user event (not sure what event that would be), so that it can be "faded in" again?

Comment: Hi @andrewJames, you're on the right track. Previous solutions I've had (which have worked) were able to fade it in by making it essentially invisible at first via css, then the click fades it in.... but it just doesn't seem to work with this datatable which does .draw()